# CURLOPT_FILE don't write headers

Tags: php

I need to download a large file and also need to get the headers in order to get the redirect location (status code 302).

I use this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
```

Now the problem is the following:

It is writing the header data as well to the output file.

Is there a way to only write the content?

## Edit:

Just to make it clear. All i want is to get the headers, but i want that only the body get's written to the file. Also please keep in mind that i can't store the body data into a variable since its a video data and therefore to big (memory_limit).

Comment: Have you tried `curl_setopt(CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER, '/dev/null')`?  I don't recall 100% the use for that option, but I *think* it's what you want.  (Not near a terminal to test.)

Comment: But then i don't have the header anymore. I need the header, but i dont want it in the file. So i guess the easiest solution would be to get it with regex from the outout file, but i am not very good at regex.

Comment: Which data? There is no data needed in order to answer the question.

Comment: Well if you need to pull certain data from the file, how can we write a regular expression without knowing?

Comment: As i said there is a empty line between the header data and the body data. So everything above this line should get fetched and then deleted from the file.

Comment: Not near a terminal, can't test, so commenting: either (a) work with the grain and write the header out to a separate file and read it back in, or (b) return transfer, looping till you hit a blank line and write out to your file. The least server intensive is likely (a).

Comment: Sorry but i do not know what you mean with the (a). What's the "grain"? Hoe cna i write the headers to a seperate file? Thanks

Comment: By "with the grain" I mean use `curl_setopt(CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER, '/path/to/some/file/headers.txt')` then you can read them in with `file_get_contents()` then `unlink()` to remove it.  At least, I think that will work -- again, not near my terminal. If it works or not, let us know!

Comment: Thanks. I just answered this question. It works fine. Just a note for you: You need to prove a file handle to that curl option instead of a filepath (string). Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the help of @Bishop i was able to get the working solution:

```
    $url = 'example.com';
    $file = fopen('body.txt', 'w');
    $file_header = fopen('headers.txt', 'w')
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER, $file_header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $file);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
```

Now i have the header in a seperate file and can get it from there by using:

```
    file_get_contents('headers.txt');
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution