# How can I save a file from dropbox on a server using PHP

Tags: php, dropbox

I'm trying to fetch a file from Dropbox using PHP and save it on my server, but not with succes so far. This is what I came up with:

```
$file = fopen('factura-17891.pdf', "w+");

$headers = array(
    'Authorization: Bearer <token>',
    'Dropbox-API-Arg: {"path": "factura-17891.pdf"}'
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $file);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

fclose($file);
```

It creates a file with the correct name but I get this error when I open the file:

> Something went wrong. Don't worry, your files are still safe and the
> Dropboxers have been notified. Check out our Help Center and forums
> for help, or head back to home.

Can anyone see what the problem is with the code above, or am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe obvious but did you replace `<token>` with the actual token?

Comment: Yes indeed, I removed it for security reasons.

Comment: I think this is the same issue kindly check 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20821318/curlopt-file-dont-write-headers/20826406)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I plug in a valid access token and path to the code you shared, and inspect the content of the downloaded file, I see it is:

> Error in call to API function "files/download": Bad HTTP "Content-Type" header: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".  Expecting one of "text/plain", "text/plain; charset=utf-8", "application/octet-stream", "application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8".

You can fix that by setting the 'Content-Type' header accordingly in your `$headers`.

Also, note that the `path` you supply in `Dropbox-API-Arg` should start with a `/`.

(And for reference, you should check the status code to see if the call failed or not.)

Comment: Thanks Greg, the issue was resolved by adjusting the path and the header info.